# C Programming what happens exactly with this recursive function

Tags: c, recursion

i have this function that when i start it prints only even numbers of the entered parameter can anyone explain to me what exactly happens in this function and how it ends up getting the even numbers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int what(int x){

    if (x == 0)
        return 0;
    if (x % 2 == 0)
        return what(x / 10) * 10 + x % 10;
    return what(x / 10);
}


int main(){
    printf("%d\n",what(145825));
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
482
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour when `x` is odd.  The function doesn't return a value when `x` is odd — and you explicitly pass an odd value to it. That means that any result is permissible, including a crash, or a different answer each time it is run, etc.  It isn't clear that the recursion terminates when `x` is even.

Comment: Q; What debugger do you have available?  STRONG SUGGESTION: learn to use your debugger r - single step through your program to SEE what it's doing.  Q: What compiler are you using? Do you see any warnings?

Comment: okay i will change the code for something similar

Comment: another strong suggestion : to take into account compiler warnings, and to ask the compiler to produce lot of warning/error, e.g. for gcc `-Wall -Werror -pedantic`

Comment: On second thoughts, I was misreading the recursive expression when I [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62156329/c-programming-what-happens-exactly-with-this-recursive-function#comment109930105_62156329) "It isn't clear that the recursion terminates when x is even".  It does terminate.  (At the time of the comment, the final `return what(x / 10);` was absent.)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler i said that im going to change it

Comment: Yes, and you did change it.  The first three sentences of my comment are still valid for the first version of the question; the last sentence was always incorrect (and I've acknowledged as much), but it was more or less a throwaway remark.  Now that the question is adjusted to work sanely,  what is your problem?  Can you not work out how `what()` is evaluated for 145825 on paper?  Or with a debugger?  Or with print statements?  AFAICS, it extracts the even digits from the input number.  I've not attempted to deduce what it does with negative values.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i just want to know how it works so it ends up with only even numbers

Comment: So what happens when you call `what(145825)`?  Which statements are executed?  There's a recursive call; you'll need to work out what happens when you recurse.  Then use the result of that recursion in the evaluation for `145825`.  Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Solve this with a plain loop and without recursion first. And then leave it like that - you should never use recursion that can't be tail-call optimized, if you must use recursion at all.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what happens:

The `what()` function starts with the rightmost digit (= the whole number modulo 10) and then recurses into the rest of the digits by throwing away the rightmost digit (integer division by 10 throws away the right decimal digit).

If the right digit is even it is appended to the result of the recursion by multiplying it by 10 (making space for the extra digit on the right) and adding this digit (= the whole number modulo 10).

If the right digit is odd nothing is added to the result of the recursion.

Recursion stops when there are no more digits.

A good way to figure out to make recursion is to make a table that keeps track of what happens during each step, but of course a debugger is always the best way to really check what happens.

The following table is what happens each time `what()` is called:

```
     x  recursive x  result    even?  returns
------  -----------  ------  -------  -------
145825        14582     482        -      482
       ______/             \_____________
      /                                  \
 14582         1458      48  48*10+2=     482
  1458          145       4   4*10+8=      48
   145           14       4        -        4
    14            1       0   0*10+4=       4
     1            0       0        -        0
     0            -       -        -        0
```